# Can't see my html file in view

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am trying to run a basic MEAN app. My app is working without the Angular part. 
But when I include Angular I can't see the HTML page which is in the "view" folder.

This is my server:

```
var express=require('express');
var path=require('path');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');

var index=require('./routes/index');
var tasks=require('./routes/tasks');
var port=3000;
var app=express();

/*View engine*/
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);

/*View static folder*/
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/',index);
app.use('/api',tasks);
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('The application is running on port '+port);
});
```

This is my route to index under "routes" directory:

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req, res, next){
    res.render('index.html');
})
module.exports=router;
```

My Angular code is living in client/app directory.
I am typing `npm start` when I am in myapp/client directory in the terminal.
I get "Can't get/" and in the terminal, I see "404 GET /index.html"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This means that when You open root route (`/` uri) it will render `index.html` file:

```
router.get('/',function(req, res, next){
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

And this means that Your view files (in Your question `index.html` file) are in `views` folder:

```
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

If You want index.html to be rendered by EJS so put `index.html` file into `views` folder (not to `client` folder).

and open Your app directly: `http://localhost:3000/`

p.s. if You want to open index.html like this: `http://localhost:3000/index.html`

do following:

make sure Your `routes/index.js` has this content:

```
const
  express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

const renderViewFile = (filename) => (req, res) => res.render(filename);

router.get('/', renderViewFile('index.html'));
router.get('/index.html', renderViewFile('index.html'));

module.exports = router;
```

or: `put index.html file into client folder and it will be served as static file`

Comment: My index.html is under myapp\views\ and not in myapp\views\client and it is still is not working :(

Comment: @TuviaKhusid ok, so add addtional route to serve `/index.html` in fact logs are saying that You were trying to access file from browser like this: `http://localhost:3000/index.html` that of course will not be accessible, cuz route `/index.html` will be handled by expressjs router as usual route and of course will not be accessible because of static middleware looks to `client` folder

Comment: @TuviaKhusid check my last updated answer, hope it suits Your needs

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Checking right now with putting the html file in client folder. I see the page but I have errors. Will try with additional route as you've recommended

Comment: I have done exactly like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFP0oXNNveg&spfreload=10 and here it is working. He is using the html file under myapp/view directory and it is working for him. Not for me :(

Comment: @TuviaKhusid (: I did not find where in video he opens: `http://localhost:3000/index.html`  http://joxi.ru/DrlEE6hvKNo6mP